# XSLT Conversion - INNERHTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, dita

I posted a question yesterday with great success, it did not exactly give me what I needed but certainly more than enough to put me on the right path. I ran into another difficulty and was hoping to find similar guidance.

I have a document with several different types of elements, some which can be nested within others. I need to remove all tags and leave only the inner HTML whenever a certain element is present.

For example, if the element pnum is present, I need to take the whole element and remove any inner elements, leaving behind only the inner html.

input:

```
<li>
    <pnum>
     blah blah
    <linum>hello hello</linum>
    good bye
    <title>good morning</title>
    </pnum>
</li>
```

output:

```
<li>
    blah blah
    hello hello
    good bye
    good morning
<li>
```

I was able to do this using HTMLAGILITYPACK, but I had to traverse every node and the performance is not great. I am wondering if there is a quicker XSLT transform I can perform on the doc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where you have taken the term `innerHTML` from but since IE 4 it usually includes the markup so your request to strip markup does not seem to be related to innerHTML.

As for XSLT, you can use

```
<xsl:template match="li[.//pnum]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to have any `li` element with a `pnum` descendant transformed to an `li` with only the text contents.

Comment: sorry innerHTML was just my way of trying to convey i needed the text enclosed in the tags without the actual tags itself.

i will try your solution and report back shortly, thank you!

Comment: i tried this but it unfortunately does not seem to work at all.

   `<xsl:template match="p[.//ph]">
          <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
`
on the following does nothing, perhaps i made an error:

 ` <p class="- topic/p ">
                            <ph class="- topic/ph">
                                <ph class="- topic/ph ">blah</ph>
                            </ph>
</p>`

Comment: http://xsltransform.net/ejivdGY is an online sample with the input of your question and my suggestion and shows the wanted output.

Comment: And http://xsltransform.net/ejivdGY/1 is an adaption that also processes the input from your comment.